# Database hosts array is empty

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, environment-variables, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, laravel-artisan

I am using elastic Beanstalk deployment for my Laravel project.I have set up my env properties in AWS beanstalk configuration.
[image]

When i ssh to beanstalk ec2 and type any php artisan commands like `php artsan migrate`, i got the error `"Database hosts array is empty. (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = ? and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')"`.
I have a valid RDS database and working laravel project.Why can't i type any of the artisan commands.The artisan commands are working when i am manually copying to the beanstalk ec2.Why it is not listening to aws env properties ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the artisan commands work when you manually copy the project to the Elastic Beanstalk EC2 instance but not when you run them through SSH, it suggests that the environment variables are not being loaded properly when using SSH.

When you manually copy the project, the environment variables might be sourced from the `.env` file present in your project directory. However, when running commands through SSH, the environment variables need to be set explicitly.

A. SSH into the EC2 instance using the command:

```
ssh -i your-key.pem ec2-user@your-instance-ip
```

B. Change the current working directory to the root directory of your Laravel project. For example:

```
cd /var/www/html/your-laravel-project
```

C. Run the artisan commands prefixed with the export command to set the environment variables explicitly. For example:

```
export DB_HOST=your-db-host
export DB_USERNAME=your-db-username
export DB_PASSWORD=your-db-password
php artisan migrate
```

By explicitly exporting the environment variables before running the artisan commands, you ensure that the variables are set and available for the Laravel application to use.

If you have many environment variables to set, it might be cumbersome to manually export each one. In that case, you could consider creating a script that exports all the required environment variables and then runs the artisan command.

Comment: This doesnt satisfy my requirement

Comment: You can try loading the environment variables using a script or by sourcing the .env file before running the artisan commands. For example: `source /var/www/html/your-laravel-project/.env`
`php artisan migrate`

Comment: It's possible that there is a conflict between the environment variables set in the AWS Beanstalk configuration and the environment variables defined in the `.env` file of your Laravel project. When running artisan commands manually after copying the project, the environment variables from the `.env` file are used, overriding the AWS environment properties. Make sure there is no conflicting configuration between the two sources.

Comment: no there is not any conflict between Beanstalk env and projects .env

Comment: try `eb php artisan migrate`

Comment: Please review and ensure that you log in to the correct SSH interface.